# Creating objects in parallel with Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, I have a code:

```
Graph[] graphs = new Graph[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    graphs[i] = new Graph();
    Graph g = graphs[i];
    g.subgraphs = new Graph[100 - i];
    g.leaves = new HashSet<Integer>();
    g.targets = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>(l - i);
    g.weights = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(l - i);
}
```

I wish to write a parallel code. Could you please help me here learning Java threading. So I added this code:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // some code to run in parallel
        }
    });
    threads[i].start();
}

// as far as I understood this waits until threads above are finishing
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    try {
        threads[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I can copy the code from the loop when I create my custom `Graph` objects but I need to pass somehow an index `i` (which is from `0` to `100`) to a `run()` method.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Java` you can only reference `final` fields from anonymous inner classes, so you need declare an `final` variable `j` to access the index:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  final int j = i;
  threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // some code to run in parallel
      System.out.println(j);
    }
  });
  threads[i].start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to maximize performance, then your best bet is almost certainly to do *no parallelism at all here*.  Creating a few hundred `HashMap`s will almost certainly be cheaper than starting up any new threads.

Answer (score 1):

I know multithreading is not suitable for instantiating objects, but I support you to practise coding skills personally. so just try it and learn from the real result.

Actually, since Java SE 1.5, low level multithreading code is rarely used. because the concurrent package comes up. try to learn from `Executor`, `ExecutorService` and `CompletionService`.

See [Perform N tasks in parallel](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=247) and [Understanding java.util.concurrent.CompletionService](http://markusjais.com/understanding-java-util-concurrent-completionservice/)